# Dropdown data based on user login in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to display warehouse data depend on user login on my transfer products view, I have a `warehouse_id` in my user table. Here I di so far.

Warehouse Model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User::class');
    }
```

User Model:

```
public function ownwarehouse()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse');
    }
```

Transfer controller:

```
$ownwarehouse= Warehouse::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

return view('transfer.create', compact('ownwarehouse'));
```

On my create transfer product blade I had dropdown from to load the warehouse based only by user login.

```
<select required name="from_warehouse_id" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select warehouse...">
    @foreach($ownwarehouse as $warehouse)
    <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}">{{$warehouse->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

but the dropdown value if empty, no data display there. I am also add to the warehouse table for user_id field and tried to fetch in dropdown with `<option value="{{$warehouse->user_id}}">{{$warehouse->name}}</option>`

but the results still empty. Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: And the controller part returning this view is where?

Comment: Hi @dbf, question edited with the return view :(

Comment: your code looks clear so far, try to `dd` `$ownwarehouse` in your controller and see the output, check also for the authenticated user id and check your database records.

Comment: You're creating a relation but you're not using it. Wouldn't be `$user = Auth::user(); $ownwarehouse = $user->ownwarehouse;` be easier? Did you execute a test in Tinker to see if the relationship works? E.g `User::find(1)->ownwarehouse;` and make sure you have linked data to test.

Comment: Try adding foreign and primary keys to your relation functions.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudAbdelgawad, tried it on controller and also on view blade, but return empty. Also checked the db record :(

Comment: finally got it working using where condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a one to many relationship between user and warehouse with this condition that every `user` can have many `warehouse`. So, it means you need to have `user_id` column in warehouse table.

Rewrite relationship methods in `User` and `Warehouse` models as below:

In **User** model:

```
public function ownwarehouse()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse', 'user_id');
}
```

And in **Warehouse** model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

You can write your query on `user` instance as below:

```
$ownwarehouses = Auth::user()->ownwarehouse;
```

And pass the `$ownwarehouses` to the view.

Comment: Hi @babak-ashrafi, tried as your suggestion but the data return [] in view. how exactly to pass in blade? I have the schema on the Warehouse table is, `id`, `warehousename`, `user_id`

Comment: you can pass data to view using `compact` such as `return view('template.blade.php', compact('warehouses'));`

Comment: Are you sure that you have inserted any data to database?

Answer (score 0):

Define database table to use in your warehouse model.

```
protected $table = 'warehouses';
```